# Getting an error that reads: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.artist'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run the following code, which I found in an AI for Python book.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

from utilities import visualize_classifier

# Load input data
input_file = 'data_decision_trees.txt'
data = np.loadtxt(input_file, delimiter=',')
X, y = data[:, :-1], data[:, -1]

# Separate input data into two classes based on labels
class_0 = np.array(X[y==0])
class_1 = np.array(X[y==1])

# Visualize input data
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(class_0[:, 0], class_0[:, 1], s=75, facecolors='black', 
        edgecolors='black', linewidth=1, marker='x')
plt.scatter(class_1[:, 0], class_1[:, 1], s=75, facecolors='white', 
        edgecolors='black', linewidth=1, marker='o')
plt.title('Input data')

# Split data into training and testing datasets 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=5)

# Decision Trees classifier 
params = {'random_state': 0, 'max_depth': 4}
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(**params)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
visualize_classifier(classifier, X_train, y_train, 'Training dataset')

y_test_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
visualize_classifier(classifier, X_test, y_test, 'Test dataset')

# Evaluate classifier performance
class_names = ['Class-0', 'Class-1']
print("\n" + "#"*40)
print("\nClassifier performance on training dataset\n")
print(classification_report(y_train, classifier.predict(X_train), target_names=class_names))
print("#"*40 + "\n")

print("#"*40)
print("\nClassifier performance on test dataset\n")
print(classification_report(y_test, y_test_pred, target_names=class_names))
print("#"*40 + "\n")

plt.show()
```

When I try running the code above, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.artist'
```

It's a little weird, because I don't have anything in the code named  'matplotlib.artist'.  So, this must be a dependency on something in the code that I'm running.  The code is definitely relying heavily on scikit learn, so I made sure to update all packages before re-running the code above.

```
conda update scikit-learn
```

I'm still getting the same error:

```
No module named 'matplotlib.artist'
```

Comment: did you solve it? I have the same problem as mentioned here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58746040/no-module-named-matplotlib-artist

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted a similar issue on Github, who recommended reinstalling matplotlib.

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6771/