# No module named 'matplotlib.artist'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I faced with this error

```
No module named 'matplotlib.artist'
```

here is the complete error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-cf8446fccc06> in <module>
      5 import numpy as np
      6 #import seaborn as sns
----> 7 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      8 from warnings import filterwarnings
      9 filterwarnings('ignore')

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>
     30 from cycler import cycler
     31 import matplotlib
---> 32 import matplotlib.colorbar
     33 import matplotlib.image
     34 from matplotlib import rcsetup, style

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>
     25 
     26 import matplotlib as mpl
---> 27 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     28 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
     29 import matplotlib.collections as collections

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.artist'
```

from yesterday when I want to use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

or

```
import seaborn as sns
```

I am using  3.7.4, matplotlib 3.1.1,seaborn 0.9.0
here is the full pip list

```
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- ---------
-atplotlib                         3.1.1
alabaster                          0.7.12
anaconda-client                    1.7.2
anaconda-navigator                 1.9.7
anaconda-project                   0.8.3
asn1crypto                         1.0.1
astroid                            2.3.1
astropy                            3.2.1
atomicwrites                       1.3.0
attrs                              19.2.0
Babel                              2.7.0
backcall                           0.1.0
backports.functools-lru-cache      1.5
backports.os                       0.1.1
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0
backports.tempfile                 1.0
backports.weakref                  1.0.post1
beautifulsoup4                     4.8.0
bitarray                           1.0.1
bkcharts                           0.2
bleach                             3.1.0
bokeh                              1.3.4
boto                               2.49.0
Bottleneck                         1.2.1
certifi                            2019.9.11
cffi                               1.12.3
chardet                            3.0.4
Click                              7.0
cloudpickle                        1.2.2
clyent                             1.2.2
colorama                           0.4.1
comtypes                           1.1.7
conda                              4.7.12
conda-build                        3.18.9
conda-package-handling             1.6.0
conda-verify                       3.4.2
contextlib2                        0.6.0
cryptography                       2.7
cycler                             0.10.0
Cython                             0.29.13
cytoolz                            0.10.0
dask                               2.5.2
decorator                          4.4.0
defusedxml                         0.6.0
distributed                        2.5.2
docutils                           0.15.2
entrypoints                        0.3
et-xmlfile                         1.0.1
fastcache                          1.1.0
filelock                           3.0.12
Flask                              1.1.1
fsspec                             0.5.2
future                             0.17.1
gevent                             1.4.0
glob2                              0.7
greenlet                           0.4.15
h5py                               2.9.0
HeapDict                           1.0.1
html5lib                           1.0.1
idna                               2.8
imageio                            2.6.0
imagesize                          1.1.0
importlib-metadata                 0.23
ipykernel                          5.1.2
ipython                            7.8.0
ipython-genutils                   0.2.0
ipywidgets                         7.5.1
isort                              4.3.21
itsdangerous                       1.1.0
jdcal                              1.4.1
jedi                               0.15.1
Jinja2                             2.10.3
joblib                             0.13.2
json5                              0.8.5
jsonschema                         3.0.2
jupyter                            1.0.0
jupyter-client                     5.3.3
jupyter-console                    6.0.0
jupyter-core                       4.5.0
jupyterlab                         1.1.4
jupyterlab-server                  1.0.6
keyring                            18.0.0
kiwisolver                         1.1.0
lazy-object-proxy                  1.4.2
libarchive-c                       2.8
llvmlite                           0.29.0
locket                             0.2.0
lxml                               4.4.1
MarkupSafe                         1.1.1
matplotlib                         3.1.1
mccabe                             0.6.1
menuinst                           1.4.16
mistune                            0.8.4
mkl-fft                            1.0.14
mkl-random                         1.1.0
mkl-service                        2.3.0
mock                               3.0.5
more-itertools                     7.2.0
mpmath                             1.1.0
msgpack                            0.6.1
multipledispatch                   0.6.0
navigator-updater                  0.2.1
nbconvert                          5.6.0
nbformat                           4.4.0
networkx                           2.3
nltk                               3.4.5
nose                               1.3.7
notebook                           6.0.1
numba                              0.45.1
numexpr                            2.7.0
numpy                              1.16.5
numpydoc                           0.9.1
olefile                            0.46
openpyxl                           3.0.0
packaging                          19.2
pandas                             0.25.1
pandocfilters                      1.4.2
parso                              0.5.1
partd                              1.0.0
path.py                            12.0.1
pathlib2                           2.3.5
patsy                              0.5.1
pep8                               1.7.1
pickleshare                        0.7.5
Pillow                             6.2.0
pip                                19.2.3
pkginfo                            1.5.0.1
pluggy                             0.13.0
ply                                3.11
progressbar2                       3.42.0
prometheus-client                  0.7.1
prompt-toolkit                     2.0.10
psutil                             5.6.3
py                                 1.8.0
pycodestyle                        2.5.0
pycosat                            0.6.3
pycparser                          2.19
pycrypto                           2.6.1
pycurl                             7.43.0.3
pyflakes                           2.1.1
Pygments                           2.4.2
pykg2vec                           0.0.48
pylint                             2.4.2
pyodbc                             4.0.27
pyOpenSSL                          19.0.0
pyparsing                          2.4.2
pyreadline                         2.1
pyrsistent                         0.15.4
PySocks                            1.7.1
pytest                             5.2.1
pytest-arraydiff                   0.3
pytest-astropy                     0.5.0
pytest-doctestplus                 0.4.0
pytest-openfiles                   0.4.0
pytest-remotedata                  0.3.2
python-dateutil                    2.8.0
python-utils                       2.3.0
pytz                               2019.3
PyWavelets                         1.0.3
pywin32                            223
pywinpty                           0.5.5
PyYAML                             5.1.2
pyzmq                              18.1.0
QtAwesome                          0.6.0
qtconsole                          4.5.5
QtPy                               1.9.0
requests                           2.22.0
rope                               0.14.0
ruamel-yaml                        0.15.46
scikit-image                       0.15.0
scikit-learn                       0.21.3
scipy                              1.3.1
seaborn                            0.9.0
Send2Trash                         1.5.0
setuptools                         41.4.0
simplegeneric                      0.8.1
singledispatch                     3.4.0.3
six                                1.12.0
snowballstemmer                    2.0.0
sortedcollections                  1.1.2
sortedcontainers                   2.1.0
soupsieve                          1.9.3
Sphinx                             2.2.0
sphinx-gallery                     0.4.0
sphinx-rtd-theme                   0.4.3
sphinxcontrib-applehelp            1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-devhelp              1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp             1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-jsmath               1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp               1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml      1.1.3
sphinxcontrib-websupport           1.1.2
spyder                             3.3.6
spyder-kernels                     0.5.2
SQLAlchemy                         1.3.9
statsmodels                        0.10.1
sympy                              1.4
tables                             3.5.2
tblib                              1.4.0
terminado                          0.8.2
testpath                           0.4.2
toolz                              0.10.0
tornado                            6.0.3
tqdm                               4.36.1
traitlets                          4.3.3
unicodecsv                         0.14.1
urllib3                            1.24.2
wcwidth                            0.1.7
webencodings                       0.5.1
Werkzeug                           0.16.0
wheel                              0.33.6
widgetsnbextension                 3.5.1
win-inet-pton                      1.1.0
win-unicode-console                0.5
wincertstore                       0.2
wrapt                              1.11.2
xlrd                               1.2.0
XlsxWriter                         1.2.1
xlwings                            0.15.10
xlwt                               1.3.0
zict                               1.0.0
zipp                               0.6.0
```

conda lsit gives me this:

```
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
anaconda                  2019.10                  py37_0
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0
anaconda-project          0.8.3                      py_0
asn1crypto                1.0.1                    py37_0
astroid                   2.3.1                    py37_0
astropy                   3.2.1            py37he774522_0
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1
attrs                     19.2.0                     py_0
babel                     2.7.0                      py_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
backports                 1.0                        py_2
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.5                        py_2
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1
beautifulsoup4            4.8.0                    py37_0
bitarray                  1.0.1            py37he774522_0
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0
blosc                     1.16.3               h7bd577a_0
bokeh                     1.3.4                    py37_0
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0
bottleneck                1.2.1            py37h452e1ab_1
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2019.8.28                     0
certifi                   2019.9.11                py37_0
cffi                      1.12.3           py37h7a1dbc1_0
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003
click                     7.0                      py37_0
cloudpickle               1.2.2                      py_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0
comtypes                  1.1.7                    py37_0
conda                     4.7.12                   py37_0
conda-build               3.18.9                   py37_3
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py37h62dcd97_0
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         3
contextlib2               0.6.0                      py_0
cryptography              2.7              py37h7a1dbc1_0
curl                      7.65.3               h2a8f88b_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
cython                    0.29.13          py37ha925a31_0
cytoolz                   0.10.0           py37he774522_0
dask                      2.5.2                      py_0
dask-core                 2.5.2                      py_0
decorator                 4.4.0                    py37_1
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
distributed               2.5.2                      py_0
docutils                  0.15.2                   py37_0
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37he774522_0
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0
freetype                  2.9.1                ha9979f8_1
fsspec                    0.5.2                      py_0
future                    0.17.1                   py37_0
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0
gevent                    1.4.0            py37he774522_0
glob2                     0.7                        py_0
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37hfa6e2cd_0
h5py                      2.9.0            py37h5e291fa_0
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
imageio                   2.6.0                    py37_0
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0
importlib_metadata        0.23                     py37_0
intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
ipykernel                 5.1.2            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.8.0            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0
jedi                      0.15.1                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.10.3                     py_0
joblib                    0.13.2                   py37_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
json5                     0.8.5                      py_0
jsonschema                3.0.2                    py37_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter_client            5.3.3                    py37_1
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0
jupyter_core              4.5.0                      py_0
jupyterlab                1.1.4              pyhf63ae98_0
jupyterlab_server         1.0.6                      py_0
keyring                   18.0.0                   py37_0
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37ha925a31_0
krb5                      1.16.1               hc04afaa_7
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.2            py37he774522_0
libarchive                3.3.3                h0643e63_5
libcurl                   7.65.3               h2a8f88b_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
liblief                   0.9.0                ha925a31_2
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libssh2                   1.8.2                h7a1dbc1_0
libtiff                   4.0.10               hb898794_2
libxml2                   2.9.9                h464c3ec_0
libxslt                   1.1.33               h579f668_0
llvmlite                  0.29.0           py37ha925a31_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1
lxml                      4.4.1            py37h1350720_0
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h2fa13f4_0
lzo                       2.10                 h6df0209_2
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37he774522_0
matplotlib                3.1.1            py37hc8f65d3_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
menuinst                  1.4.16           py37he774522_0
mistune                   0.8.4            py37he774522_0
mkl                       2019.4                      245
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hb782905_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.14           py37h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37h675688f_0
mock                      3.0.5                    py37_0
more-itertools            7.2.0                    py37_0
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37h74a9793_1
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0
nbconvert                 5.6.0                    py37_1
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0
networkx                  2.3                        py_0
nltk                      3.4.5                    py37_0
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2
notebook                  6.0.1                    py37_0
numba                     0.45.1           py37hf9181ef_0
numexpr                   2.7.0            py37hdce8814_0
numpy                     1.16.5           py37h19fb1c0_0
numpy-base                1.16.5           py37hc3f5095_0
numpydoc                  0.9.1                      py_0
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openpyxl                  3.0.0                      py_0
openssl                   1.1.1d               he774522_2
packaging                 19.2                       py_0
pandas                    0.25.1           py37ha925a31_0
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
parso                     0.5.1                      py_0
partd                     1.0.0                      py_0
path.py                   12.0.1                     py_0
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py37_0
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
pillow                    6.2.0            py37hdc69c19_0
pip                       19.2.3                   py37_0
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0
pluggy                    0.13.0                   py37_0
ply                       3.11                     py37_0
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         2
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0
prompt_toolkit            2.0.10                     py_0
psutil                    5.6.3            py37he774522_0
py                        1.8.0                    py37_0
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37ha925a31_2
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37hfa6e2cd_9
pycurl                    7.43.0.3         py37h7a1dbc1_0
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0
pylint                    2.4.2                    py37_0
pyodbc                    4.0.27           py37ha925a31_0
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0
pyparsing                 2.4.2                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2
pyreadline                2.1                      py37_1
pyrsistent                0.15.4           py37he774522_0
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0
pytables                  3.5.2            py37h1da0976_1
pytest                    5.2.1                    py37_0
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0
pytest-doctestplus        0.4.0                      py_0
pytest-openfiles          0.4.0                      py_0
pytest-remotedata         0.3.2                    py37_0
python                    3.7.4                h5263a28_0
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_13
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0
pywavelets                1.0.3            py37h8c2d366_1
pywin32                   223              py37hfa6e2cd_1
pywinpty                  0.5.5                 py37_1000
pyyaml                    5.1.2            py37he774522_0
pyzmq                     18.1.0           py37ha925a31_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome                 0.6.0                      py_0
qtconsole                 4.5.5                      py_0
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37hfa6e2cd_0
scikit-image              0.15.0           py37ha925a31_0
scikit-learn              0.21.3           py37h6288b17_0
scipy                     1.3.1            py37h29ff71c_0
seaborn                   0.9.0                    py37_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0
setuptools                41.4.0                   py37_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0
sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
snappy                    1.1.7                h777316e_3
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0
soupsieve                 1.9.3                    py37_0
sphinx                    2.2.0                      py_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.2                      py_0
spyder                    3.3.6                    py37_0
spyder-kernels            0.5.2                    py37_0
sqlalchemy                1.3.9            py37he774522_0
sqlite                    3.30.0               he774522_0
statsmodels               0.10.1           py37h8c2d366_0
sympy                     1.4                      py37_0
tbb                       2019.4               h74a9793_0
tblib                     1.4.0                      py_0
terminado                 0.8.2                    py37_0
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0
tk                        8.6.8                hfa6e2cd_0
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0
tornado                   6.0.3            py37he774522_0
tqdm                      4.36.1                     py_0
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0
urllib3                   1.24.2                   py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
werkzeug                  0.16.0                     py_0
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0
win_unicode_console       0.5                      py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37he774522_0
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0
xlsxwriter                1.2.1                      py_0
xlwings                   0.15.10                  py37_0
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0
xz                        5.2.4                h2fa13f4_4
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
zeromq                    4.3.1                h33f27b4_3
zict                      1.0.0                      py_0
zipp                      0.6.0                      py_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h508b16e_0
```

as you see there is something suspicious here in pip list:
-atplotlib 
I do not know what is that! it 
looks like matplotlib without first letter m

I have search a lot and did a lot of efforts based on this

[Getting an error that reads: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.artist'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162173/getting-an-error-that-reads-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-matplotlib-ar)

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6771/

like, reinstall matplotlib, reinstall anaconda ...

but it does not work! In my view, it might be something related to the path, but I can not find the solution.

I also uninstall my anaconda two times still have the problem!

any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: @tacaswell  could you please help me by your idea?

Comment: @bgbutler could you have a look at this ?

Comment: check this https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6771/

Comment: @SivaShanmugam tnx for the prompt response, but if you read my question, you see that I already mentioned that the solution did did not work for me!

Comment: If you get this error, your matplotlib installation is broken. You need to remove matplotlib and reinstall it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest tnx for the prompt response, I have done uninstall with pip moreever if you read my question I had uninstalled the anaconda! still the same error, I really do not know what is the problem

Comment: Maybe you have several python versions installed and are working with the wrong one here?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest tnx again,  I have only "Anaconda3 (python 3.7.4 )"  and "python launcher" in my control panel. any idea?

Comment: Did you install matplotlib via anaconda or via pip? You could also show the complete error trace in the question, maybe that hints at a potential source of the problem.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I checked that I have only one version python as follow: ```C:\Users\moha>py -0
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.7-64 *``` I update the complete error now...

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest it is done! now you have the complete error

Comment: Can you run `activate` Enter, `where python` in the command line

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  here is here is the result:  C:\Users\moha\python
C:\Users\moha\Anaconda3\python.exe   you are right! how can I one of them? and which one, I also put the pip list result after uninstall matplot in question

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  any idea? I really sucked up for 2 days..:(

Comment: Yes, you have two or more python versions, so you need to make sure to use the correct one when installing and running.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have removed now, the result of cmd is now:C:\Users\moha\Anaconda3\python.exe and still does not work,even I made a env and still does not work! any idea...I guess now I have one python

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I really did all, I have updated the question also. can you let me know how can I solve it....

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  any idea?

Comment: Ernest is correct, this looks like an installation issue.  Keep uninstalling things until all of your python installations are gone (anaconda, pythonxy, winpython, from python.org, from appstore, ....) and then start from scratch with exactly one source.  Based on your question, that is the best advice we can give.  This conversation be be better at https://discourse.matplotlib.org/c/community/install

Comment: @tacaswell I have done multiple times! still the same result!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  I have done all possible ways, same result any idea

Comment: having this    -atplotlib                         3.1.1 in my pip list after reinstation is wired! which is not the name of any package but matplotlib without m ..!

Answer (score 9):

Go to this location

`~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\`

There will be two folders named as

`~atplotlib`

and

`matplotlib`

Please rename `~atplotlib` to `matplotlib`

The system will ask you that there is another folder with the same name, so do you want to merge.

Select merge option.

In my case, this resolved the matter.

Comment: I spent 4 hours trying to fix this. Your answer is an absolute lifesaver!

Comment: The same worked for me, only with a different location: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\your_environment\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib`

Comment: deleting any folder starting with ~atplotlib or ~tplotlib worked for me, I couldn't replace the individual files after merging the folders, as Windows was asking me to rename them.

Comment: It worked for me too! But my path for **Python3.10** was different `~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages`

Comment: It also solved the issue with the imports of DLL files (where installing Microsoft redistributable c++ and pip install msvc-runtime didn't help at all and the error was persistent across environments). `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: The specified module could not be found.`

Answer (score 3):

I also had similar problem, the below command solved the problem, run it in anaconda command prompt.

```
conda install matplotlib --force
```

source: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6771/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using Python 3.9. I had no folder named ~atplotlib so I couldn't merge it as suggested. I however found ~andas (pandas) in site-packages which I attempted to merge but was unsuccessful.

I uninstalled matplotlib using "pip uninstall matplotlib" and then reinstalled pandas after removing all pandas folders in site-packages. I noticed the numpy was included at the same time and created a new folder ~umpy so now I just removed everything again that contained numpy, pandas or matplotlib from site-packages (after uninstalling via pip).

Then I installed the modules in the order pandas, (numpy included), matplotlib using pip. And now finally it works. Utterly confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I have done all steps including uninstalling, 
[How to remove anaconda from windows completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337928/how-to-remove-anaconda-from-windows-)

using anaconda clean, 
completely removing all folder related to python in C:\Users\myusdername
removing from path 
uninstall by anaconda

I just nopticed that the error says that 
AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py

I manually remove python form the 
AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37
r=then it works!!

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem and I used the below command. Please use this command in Anaconda prompt.

```
>conda install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

after upgrading Matplotlib check this as well

Go to this location

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\

and check the folder name ..
for some weird reason matplotlib is saved as ~atplotlib folder.

just rename ~atplotlib folder as matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Resolved by installing the 'matplotlib-base" in anaconda.

Follow the below steps for the same:

1. Open Anaconda navigator
2. Choose the "Environments"
3. Choose "base(root)" environment
4. select the option "All" then Search for "matplotlib"
5. choose matplotlib-base Then Click on  botton
6. Restart your JuputerNotebook kernal and then import the matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

in my case,for py 3.9,i have ~ite_packages and site_packages in ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39 and i cut and paste all the files from the first folder into the other folder.It works hopefully!